# How to solve this ODE (integration factor?)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Im trying to solve the following ODE:

$(x+y+1) dx + (2x +2y -1) dy = 0$

In the theory of my book these presented with the form

$P(x,y) dx + Q(x,y) dy = 0$

So for my example we have

$P(x,y) = x +y +1 , \, \, \, Q(x,y) = 2x + 2y -1$

Thus we notice that

$\dfrac{\partial}{\partial y}P(x,y) = 1 \neq \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}Q(x,y) = 2$

So the ODE is not exact. Then I would try to use an integrate factor if the following expresion depends only on $x$

$\dfrac{1}{P(t,x)} \left( \dfrac{\partial}{\partial y} P(x,y) - \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x} Q(x,y)\right) = - \dfrac{1}{x+y+1}$

but as you can see, that is not the case. Have I done something wrong? How can I solve this ODE?

Comment: Your differential equation can be rewritten as $y'(x)=\dfrac{-x-y(x)-1}{2x+2y(x)-1}$. This is a special kind of differential equation, I think it has a name, alas I don't remember it. The solutions to these differential equations are known. The substitution suggested by David H below is standard, I believe.

Comment: @GitGud What is special about that, or what is the general form for that kind of differential equiations?

Comment: I meant equations of the form $y'(x)=\dfrac{ax+by(x)+C}{Ax+By(x)+D}$.

Comment: Oh, now I recall those. Thanks @GitGud =D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: substitute $w(x)=y(x)+x$.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, is there any way to do it with integration factor, though?

Comment: Yes, an integrating factor exists. The problem is that this integrating factor will be a function of two variables instead of one, and to figure out what it is you have to solve a PDE instead of an ODE. In other words, to solve your ODE by integrating factors you must first solve a much, much more complicated problem.

Comment: I have read my theory again and now it does make sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
$\ds{\large\tt Hint}$:

> $$
> \mbox{With}\quad x \equiv u + v\quad\mbox{and}\quad y \equiv u - v\quad \mbox{you'll get}\quad
> {3u \over 1 - u}\,\dd u + \dd v = 0
> $$